# Get basic statistics from a feature server and display it in an own element in ArcGIS JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-pro, web-mapping, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I use ArcGIS Pro 2.9.0 and ArcGIS JavaScript. I am new to using my feature sets with ArcGIS JavaScript.

I have a point feature set on ArcGIS Online (https://services2.arcgis.com/iVTT0jpvWSmHS8yL/arcgis/rest/services/GPR_punkt/FeatureServer/layers) that has two attributes I want to show some basic statistics of. It is the column year and hectare.

By doing summarize and create bar chart of the summarization in ArcGIS Pro, I got exactly what I want, a simple and basic statistic over the area (in hecatare) that has been run each year:

[image: statistic]
[image: hisotgram]

The problem arises when I want to show this in my online map (located at https://kartla.xyz/html/gf.html)

I am unsure what tool is the right one for this, and I want one that does not use the current map view or anything like that. Only a statistic for all of the records.

I created a box (I found an example online) that I want to populate with this data:

> // UI-element
>
> const titleContent = document.createElement("div");
> titleContent.style.padding = "15px";
> titleContent.style.backgroundColor = "white";
> titleContent.style.width = "500px";   titleContent.innerHTML = [
> "
>
> Vi tester
>
> ",   ].join(" ");
>
> const titleExpand = new Expand({
> expandIconClass: "esri-icon-dashboard",
> expandToottip: "Summary stats",
> view: view,
> content: titleContent,
> expanded: view.widthBreakpoint !== "xsmall"   });   view.ui.add(titleExpand, "top-right");

Should I do a query inside this? Or is histogram or StatisticDefinition the best solution? I know I could just paste a picture of my findings from ArcGIS Pro, but then I have a problem when I add more data for 2021.

Comment: You could use [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) to draw diagram in your box, see for example https://observablehq.com/@d3/histogram

Comment: I was thinking how to use some of ArcGIS JavaScript modules and widgets to replicate the same results that I have done in ArcGIS Pro, then show it inside the element.

Comment: Years ago I worked on a project where we pulled data from ArcGIS Server feature services (probably via simple queries to the REST endpoints) and displayed it popup windows using [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/demo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript, once the layer has loaded, you can use a "group by" query on the layer to get the summary statistics that you want. Then display/format the table/chart as you wish.

Snippet:

```
  gfPunkt.when(() => {
    const statsQuery = gfPunkt.createQuery();
    // create a query for both Count and Hectares
    statsQuery.outStatistics = [
      {
        onStatisticField: "hectare",
        outStatisticFieldName: "Counts",
        statisticType: "count"
      },
      {
        onStatisticField: "hectare",
        outStatisticFieldName: "Hectares",
        statisticType: "sum"
      }
    ];
    // group by year
    statsQuery.groupByFieldsForStatistics = ["year"];
    // return the results ordered by year
    statsQuery.orderByFields = "year";
    gfPunkt.queryFeatures(statsQuery).then(displayResults);
  });
```

Full example code at https://codepen.io/bsvensson/pen/WNZQoqO

[image: screenshot of table]

Resources:

- https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-rest-support-Query.html#groupByFieldsForStatistics
- https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#querying